# EmberJS check array of properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Array of ember Objects

```
[
  {"label":"input1_b1","isUsed":true},
  {"label":"input2_b2","isUsed":false},
  {"label":"input3_b3","isUsed":true},
  {"label":"input4_b4","isUsed":true}
]
```

I want to check whether any of the object property of this Array is changed using Ember.

Is there any solution

Comment: what's your use case?

Comment: A model has an `isDirty` property - http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isDirty

Comment: my usecase is if any object property of the array is changed , i have to show a message to user, u have changed few things

Comment: what is the trigger for the check? Should it be a computed property or you want to check it by your js code?

Comment: I want to check by JS Code

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
something_changed: function() {
  console.log('something changed');
}.observes(array.@each.some-property-name)
```

Comment: that should do that trick - if you are inside a simple ArrayController something more literal like this should work :  function() { }.property("model.@each.foobar")